Problem with LiveData variables in ViewModel and passing data to View
Github Project Link
This is my project, if you have a moment and would look at what it's about, I would be grateful.
So i my LoginViewModel.kt i have two variables and some fun working on LiveData:
private val _loggedInUser = MutableLiveData<User?>()
var loggedInUser: LiveData<User?> = _loggedInUser

I have also fetching function to this variables:
private fun fetchLoggedInUser(username: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val user = userRepository.getUserByUsername(username)
            Log.d("LoginViewModel", "Fetched user: $user")
            _loggedInUser.value = user

            if (user != null) {
                Log.d("LoginViewModel", "_loggedInUser set to: ${_loggedInUser.value}")
                Log.d("LoginViewModel", "loggedInUser set to: ${loggedInUser.value}")

            } else {
                Log.d("LoginViewModel", "No user found for username: $username")
            }
        }
    }

This function is called in the user login function also i LoginViewModel:
fun login(navController: NavController) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            usernameErrorMessage = null
            passwordErrorMessage = null

            val hashedInputPassword = hashPassword(password)

            val user = userRepository.getUser(username, hashedInputPassword)

            if (user != null) {
                // Pobierz dane użytkownika
                fetchLoggedInUser(username)
                loginSuccess = true

                // Przekazanie nazwy użytkownika do HomepageView
                navController.navigate("HomepageView/${user.username}")
            } else {
                usernameErrorMessage = "Invalid username or password"
                passwordErrorMessage = "Invalid username or password"
            }
        }
    }

The logs show that the variables are being assigned:
2024-10-02 20:45:02.497  7595-7595  LoginViewModel          com.example.pracainynierska          D  Fetched user: User(id=1, username=Andrzej, password=03ac674216f3e15c761ee1a5e255f067953623c8b388b4459e13f978d7c846f4, email=andrzej@wp.pl, userPhotoPath=app/src/main/res/raw/user_photo_2.json)
2024-10-02 20:45:02.497  7595-7595  LoginViewModel          com.example.pracainynierska          D  _loggedInUser set to: User(id=1, username=Andrzej, password=03ac674216f3e15c761ee1a5e255f067953623c8b388b4459e13f978d7c846f4, email=andrzej@wp.pl, userPhotoPath=app/src/main/res/raw/user_photo_2.json)
2024-10-02 20:45:02.497  7595-7595  LoginViewModel          com.example.pracainynierska          D  loggedInUser set to: User(id=1, username=Andrzej, password=03ac674216f3e15c761ee1a5e255f067953623c8b388b4459e13f978d7c846f4, email=andrzej@wp.pl, userPhotoPath=app/src/main/res/raw/user_photo_2.json)

But this fun shows me that val userId is null and this is also in LoginViewModel:
fun updateUserPhotoPath(photoPath: String) {
        val userId = loggedInUser.value?.id
        Log.d("UserImagePicker", "User ID before updating photo path: ${loggedInUser.value?.id}")
        Log.d("UserImagePicker", "New photo path: $photoPath")

        if (userId != null) {
            Log.d("LoginViewModel", "Updating user photo path for userId: $userId with photoPath: $photoPath")
            viewModelScope.launch {
                //userRepository.updateUserPhotoPath(userId, photoPath)
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("LoginViewModel", "User ID is null, cannot update photo path.")
        }
    }

And in HomepageView i have variable loggedInUser which also shows me null:
val loggedInUser by loginViewModel.loggedInUser.observeAsState()

**I dont know how to read data from LiveData variables in ViewModel and in the UI(View) can anyone help?
**
I dont know how to read data from LiveData variables in ViewModel and in the UI(View) can anyone help?

Try replacing liveData/mutableLiveData with StateFlow/MutableStateFlow, and observeAsState() with collectAsStateWithLifecycle().

are you call fetchLoggedInUser method? you must first call fetchLoggedInUser and later call fetchLoggedInUser method.
